# Converting non reactive variables from/to ref

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have some features and variables coming from a non-Vue 3rd party library.
I want to register that globally and make them Vue-friendly. So, I turn them into `reactive` values, and register them into `globalProperties`. When I use them, I point to the `$instance` and spread them into `ToRef` again.

My question is, is this `toRef` necessary or redundant because it is already `reactive` at the beginning? Or did I use `reactive` too early, because `toRef` will cover the values as a reference in the use hook, `reactive` doesn't provide any extra cover to it?

I apologise if the question doesn't make sense, this converting normal variables or objects from/to a reference proxy concept is new to me, I just want to use the ref from Vue to look after the 3rd party variables. I am a bit confused as I am fairly new to Vue.

The following is an example about `reactive` and `toRef`:

**myPlugin.ts**

```
import {status, feature } from "some-3rd-party-library";
import { App, reactive } from "vue";

export const myPlugin = {
  install: (app App) = {
    const instance = reactive({ //<<<<<<<<<
      status,
      feature,
      //whatever is needed...
    });
    app.config.globalProperties.$myinstance = instance;
  }
};
```

**main.ts**

```
  app.use(myPlugin);
```

**useMyPlugin.ts**

```
  import { getCurrentInstance, ref, toRefs } from "vue";

  export const useMyPlugin = {
    const { status, feature } = toRefs( //<<<<<<<<<
      const global = getCurrentInstance();
      global.appContext.config.globalProperties.$myinstance 
    );
    return {
      status, 
      feature
    }
  };
```

Comment: Just my thoughts.  I don't think you used reactive too early, I think you need the global piece of state to be reactive for anyone using it.  The `toRefs` is redundant, in the sense that you already have reactivity.  But it may make sense if that's the api you want to provide.

Comment: Looks ok. Could be done the opposite way, like `$myinstance = reactive(inject('myPluginRefs'))`, but it makes sense to use reactive for $myinstance. It's common for composables to return refs for loosely related reactive values, toRefs serves the purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toRefs()` is necessary when you want to convert a reactive object into an object where each property is a separate ref. This is particularly useful when you want to destructure reactive properties inside the `setup()` function.

Here's a basic example of integrate non-Vue 3rd party library:

```
import { createApp, reactive, toRefs } from 'vue';
import { someFeature, anotherFeature } from 'nonVueLibrary';

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    // Make non-Vue features reactive
    const reactiveSomeFeature = reactive(someFeature);
    const reactiveAnotherFeature = reactive(anotherFeature);

    // Register reactive variables as global properties
    app.config.globalProperties.$instance = {
      reactiveSomeFeature,
      reactiveAnotherFeature,
    };

    return {
      // Spread reactive variables into toRefs() if needed
      ...toRefs(reactiveSomeFeature),
      ...toRefs(reactiveAnotherFeature),
    };
  },
});

app.mount('#app');
```